# Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps And net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 Causes Debugger Error

Tags: c#, maui

When using the basic example of the new Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps And net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 I run into an error within net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0. I am visual studio 2022 community on windows 10. The error occurs when creating the windows application.

These following images are from my project setup:

**My Visual Studio Setup**
[image: Visual Studio Community 2022 debug setup]

**The file the error occurs within the net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 framework**
[image: Within the net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 framework is where the error occurred]

**The Map control added to the UI**
[image: The MAP control added to the UI]

**This is the implementation MauiProgram.cs**
[image: The implementation in]

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: When VS stops at error, in Locals Pane, what is the message of the exception (variable `e`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official document:

> The Map control isn't supported on Windows due to lack of a map control in WinUI. However, you can still launch the native map app from your .NET MAUI app on WinUI, to display a map at a specific location or to perform navigation.

So you can try to test your code on the android or ios platoform. For more information, you can check the official document about [the Map Control in the maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-7.0).